# Find ONLY soft deleted rows with Sequelize

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm running a database on sequelize and sqlite and I use soft-deletes to basically archive the data.

I'm aware that with `.findAll(paranoid: false)` I can find all rows including the soft deleted ones. However I would like to find ONLY the soft-deleted ones.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or is there perhaps a way to do "set operations" with two data results, like finding the relative complement of one in the other?

Comment: soft delete is having a `deleted_at` (column name can be different for you) updated with a datetime value when the data is deleted. So, you can query with where option, `deleted_at` is not null.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does what I needed.
In my case it looked like this: `model.findAll({ where: {deletedAt: {[Op.not]: null}}, paranoid: false });`
Maybe you wanna post this as an answer to the question, so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can add the following condition to where.

```
deletedAt: { [Op.not]: null }
```

For example like this:

```
const projects = await db.Project.findAndCountAll({
        paranoid: false,
        order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
        where: { employer_id: null, deletedAt: { [Op.not]: null } },
        limit: parseInt(size),
        offset: (page - 1) * parseInt(size),
});
```